# How to remove duplicate "keys" in a list and compute the mean of values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of lists and I need to take the average of the elements that have the same "key" (the element in position [0] within the list).

```
[[('a', 'b'), 1], [('b', 'c'), 2], [('a', 'b'), 5]]
```

And I want to display `[('a', 'b'), 3], [('b', 'c'), 2]]`. Can you please help?

Thank you!

Comment: @chepner I thought the same thing, but Op said he is looking for the mean of the elements. (1+5)/2

Comment: It is not a typo. @dfundako is right, that is what I am looking for. I want to use the element [0] as a "key" and make the mean of the elements with the same "key".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot use `collections.Counter` here, since you need to remember how many integers there are for the same "key".

I would use a `collections.defaultdict` to record the integer values in a list, using the tuples as keys (merging them in the process). Then, scan the dictionary and compute mean:

```
s = [[('a', 'b'), 1], [('b', 'c'), 2], [('a', 'b'), 5]]

import collections

c = collections.defaultdict(list)

for t,i in s:
    c[t].append(i)

# at this point c contains: {('a', 'b'): [1, 5], ('b', 'c'): [2]}

result = [(t,sum(v)//len(v)) for t,v in c.items()]

print(result)
```

prints:

```
[(('a', 'b'), 3), (('b', 'c'), 2)]
```

(or as dictionary: `result = {t:sum(v)//len(v) for t,v in c.items()}`

note that `sum(v)//len(v)` computes the mean as integer (with rounding to the lowest value). If you want the exact float value, use `sum(v)/float(len(v))` for python 2 or `sum(v)/len(v)` for python 3, or as jpp noted `statistics.mean`)

Comment: Any explanations would be nice, even if it is not preferred to provide code without attempt. Without explanations and only downvote would not help to learn. Anyways nice solution!

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to make it work for more than just 2 repeating elements?

Comment: try it with another more complex dataset, it works too.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre you are right thanks! my brain just stopped for a second!

Comment: thanks. Besides the downvote was retracted, or maybe the user was removed, dunno. Good news anyway

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but list in  "c = collections.defaultdict(list)" is not defined or used anywhere in your code, isn't the variable list supposed to be s?

Comment: `for t,i in s:
    c[t].append(i)` then we use `c` afterwards

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using `itertools.groupby` and `statistics.mean`, both available in the standard library.

```
from itertools import groupby
from statistics import mean
from operator import itemgetter

lst = [[('a', 'b'), 1], [('b', 'c'), 2], [('a', 'b'), 5]]

grouper = groupby(sorted(lst), key=itemgetter(0))
res = ((i, mean(map(itemgetter(1), j))) for i, j in grouper)

print(list(res))

# [(('a', 'b'), 3), (('b', 'c'), 2)]
```

**Explanation**

- Create an iterator from a `sorted` collection. Sorting is necessary `itertools.groupby`.
- Use a list comprehension to return a list of tuples.
- Use `statistics.mean` to calculate the mean of the second element of `groupby` elements, which we can extract via `operator.itemgetter`.

Comment: not the downvoter, but there's a catch when using groupby with sort. It introduces more complexity just for the sake of creating a oneliner. I was reminded that by Martjin Pieters once, and I'm not using that again.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, Hmm, I get the performance argument. But I don't buy performance is always important either. I'm not worried about  about DV, but I'd love to hear *why* from the downvoter. Esp since the `pandas` solution has no DV.

Comment: if you get to know this guy, I'd love to talk with him as well.. the pandas solution is better imho because it doesn't need sorting. It was posted after the downvoter had left the crime scene

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, Seems like you can never win. More than once I offer a `numpy` / `pandas` solution to a list-of-lists task and get DV because I use a 3rd party library ("It's overkill."). Yet here the complexity is too high, though for datasets of size <1000, you might even find `itertools.groupby` [outperform](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/03/22/group-by-from-scratch/) pandas.

Comment: `itertools.groupby` may outperform pandas, but not when you have to sort elements. But as we said earlier, the downvoter probably didn't care about complexity

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, For large datasets, yes. For small datasets, no. `pandas` has an overhead. My point is you can't have fixed assumptions as to usage / performance requirements. OP needs to specify whether performance is important. A DV on performance is otherwise premature.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of more options, you can also `groupby` and `mean` in pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(s)
meaned_df = df.groupby(0).mean()

        1
0        
(a, b)  3
(b, c)  2
```

then just format using [**`to_dict()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) :

```
>>> meaned_df.to_dict()[1]

[{('a', 'b'): 3}, {('b', 'c'): 2}]
```

Of course you can make it a one-liner :)

```
>> pd.DataFrame(s).groupby(0).mean().to_dict()[1]
```

outputs

```
[{('a', 'b'): 3}, {('b', 'c'): 2}]
```

Comment: Honestly, if the OP is dealing with ad hoc data frames anyway, it seems like just going whole hog and pulling in pandas is the best idea.